# R - differing number of rows error w/ predict()

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to build a linear regression predictor that will take known data (house_train) and predict a missing value in another dataset (house_test). The full training data has 8,973 rows and the test data has 1,063. I would like the end result to be two columns, id and the predicted value:

```
id   price2013
6    639400
13   340034
20   96381
```

I keep getting errors having to do with mismatched numbers.

```
Error in data.frame(id = house_test$id, price2013 = predict(my.model,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1063, 8973
```

I really only want the predicted value for price2013 that's missing in house_test. I have tried several variants and I seem to always get some variant of the numbers error. I'm new to r so I really can't find what's causing it. Thank you for any help you can give with this.

Regards,
Sandy

```
house_train=data.frame(id=c(0,1,2,3,4),
          state=c(NY,NY,IL,CA,NY),
          county=c(bronx,kings,cook,san francisco,queens),
          price2007=c(335200,471500,254600,707100,636400),
          price2013=c(294000,471600,174200,822600,681500))

house_test=data.frame(id=c(6,13,20),
          state=c(FL,TX,NY),
          county=c(marion,hidalgo,kings),
          price2007=c(265600,79900,332000))

my.model <- lm(price2013~state+county, data=house_train)

my.predictions <-data.frame(id = house_test$id, price2013 = predict(my.model, 
data=house_test))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now getting a different error message. `Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor county has new levels bossier, gilpin, grafton, harrisonburg city, hill, hunt`

Comment: What is the best way to address that? Do I need to take them out of the test set or add new data to the training set? Or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.